# ValueError: SARIMAX models require univariate `endog`. Got shape (88, 2)

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, arima, sarimax

My Dataframe(train) look like this

```
            total_mtrs   total_mtrs_2
trx_date        
2013-07-01  3449701.0   -1.362983
2013-08-01  3172872.0   -1.585093
2013-09-01  3137336.0   -1.613605
2013-10-01  3108550.0   -1.636701
2013-11-01  2981503.0   -1.738636
... ... ...
2020-06-01  4393613.0   -0.605648
2020-07-01  5173863.0   0.020375
2020-08-01  5629610.0   0.386038
2020-09-01  6417227.0   1.017972
2020-10-01  6424951.0   1.024169
```

I can perform every operation it cant show any error and compile successfully but then I train Time series model with this

```
arma_mod20 = ARIMA(train, order=(0,1,0)).fit()
print(arma_mod20.params)
```

It can shows an error.

```
ValueError: SARIMAX models require univariate `endog`. Got shape (88, 2).
```

I search on stack overflow and google as well I am unable to find any solution.
I use `ARIMA` model but it throws an error of `SARIMAX` model.

Comment: I think what the error says is that the endogenous variable should have a single dimension, i.e. single column.

Answer (score 0):

try using a specific column name like in your case it is,

```
arma_mod20 = ARIMA(train.total_mtrs, order=(0,1,0)).fit()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to add a specific Column name in your Dataframe. This error happened to me after changing the old lib `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model` to `statsmodels.tsa.arima.model` (note the change in model name with underscore).

For your use case try this:

```py
rma_mod20 = ARIMA(train.total_mtrs, order=(0,1,0)).fit()
```

OR

```py
rma_mod20 = ARIMA(train.total_mtrs_2, order=(0,1,0)).fit()
```